# Change the way the assistant reads out numbers

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, api-ai

Is there a way to change how google assistant reads out numbers?

For example, 108 is a number, and assistant reads it out as "*one hundred eight*." Here, instead of "*one hundred eight*" I want the assistant to speak like "*one oh eight*".

Answer (score 4):

Probably. While there are some ways you can change how it reads out numbers using the `<say-as>` [ssml tag](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml), you still don't have complete control over how it pronounces each number.

So

```
<speak>
  <say-as interpret-as="cardinal">108</say-as>
</speak>
```

speaks it the default way - "one hundred eight" (at least for US English. Different locales may speak it differently).

```
<speak>
  <say-as interpret-as="characters">108</say-as>
</speak>
```

says it the way you want (again, in US English): "one oh eight".

If you wanted it as "one zero eight", however, you'd be out of luck.